# box with size defined overflow only partially

Tags: html, css

So my title is weird but don't know how to explain in few words. I have a box with defined size (250px * 70px) and inside this box I have a text. This text is divides in two part. One of the part must absolutely stay visible but the other one can be cut. And the text that must stay is at the end. here is an example :

```css
.title {
  width : 250px;
  height : 70px;
  overflow : hidden;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
.stay {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title">
  <span class="optionnal" >This is a test</span>
  <span  class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a...</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
```

The first result don't cause any trouble since the text is not too big. The problem is the second one. The text is too long so i don't see the "I MUST STAY" part. What I want for the second one is what I have on the third result. But you know... Without manually cutting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make use of Javascript... Use @Temani Afif solution if you can't

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.optionnal')).forEach(el => {
  // If the text of "Optionnal" is greater than 84, then ellipse it...
  el.innerText = el.innerText.length > 84 ? el.innerText.slice(0, 84) + '...' : el.innerText
})
```

```css
.title {
  width : 250px;
  height : 70px;
  overflow : show;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
.stay {
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title">
  <span class="optionnal" >This is a test</span>
  <span  class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a...</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a *hacky* idea where you need to have the text duplicated. The trick is to always have a text placed at the bottom right of the container then the other text will have its pseudo elements creating an overlay that will hide it so that we only see the positionned text when this one is out of the container.

To better see the trick, change the white color to understand how the overlay are only hidding the positionned text.

*The "must stay" text should take one line and the 3 dots are place manually based on the length of the text*

```css
.title {
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin:5px 0;
}

.title::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 13px;
  color: red;
  background: #fff;
}
.title::after {
  content: '... ';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 130px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 3px;
}

.stay {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  background: #fff;
  display:inline-block;
}

.stay::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  left: -50vw;
  right: -50vw;
  background: #fff;
}

.stay::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  top:0;
  bottom: -50vh;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test a test a test is test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test a test a test is test test test test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a test</span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
<h3 class="title" data-text="I MUST STAY">
  <span class="optionnal">This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a testThis is a test This is a is a test This is a is a test This is a </span>
  <span class="stay"> I MUST STAY</span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Hey ! That's a very nice response, and I spent a lot of time trying to use it. Unfortunately my case was very specific, and your solution did not work with me. I''ll use the @Hammerbot one since it's more easily adaptable event if it's less good. Thank you for your help and take my upvote !